# NullPointerException in recording audio player android

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception, android-mediarecorder

```
package com.example.projectlayout;

import java.io.File;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Environment;

import android.os.SystemClock;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Chronometer;

import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Chronometer time;
 int i=0;
MediaRecorder recorder;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    time=(Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    String name="myrecord"+i++;
    File sdcard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    System.out.println(sdcard.toString());
    File recording=new File(sdcard,"videoRecordingFileZ");
    if(!recording.exists())
    {
    System.out.println("inside if");
    recording.mkdir();
    }
String rec=recording.getAbsolutePath()+"/Record"+".3GP";
    try{                
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
  recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(rec);                                    
    recorder.prepare();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    recorder.start();
    }}
   public void startrecording(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "START RECORDING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        time.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        time.start();
    }
public void stoprecording(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "STOP RECORDING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        time.stop();
    }
    public void showrecording(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Show RECORDING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Showlist.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

Logcat:

```
03-27 00:49:22.224: E/AndroidRuntime(470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-27 00:49:22.224: E/AndroidRuntime(470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectlayout/com.example.projectlayout.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-27 00:49:22.224: E/AndroidRuntime(470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectlayout/com.example.projectlayout.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize your MediaRecorder:

```
 MediaRecorder recorder;
```

you should do it in the onCreate method:

```
 recorder = new MediaRecorder();
```

before you make use of your `recorder` or you get a NullPointerException.

BTW: improve your code indentation (in Eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> keybord shortcut) to increase readability of your code

---

about the next problem: `IllegalStateException`:

check the [MediaRecorder state diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) from the android documentation:
[image]

and the provided example code:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
 ...
 recorder.stop();
 recorder.reset();   // You can reuse the object by going back to setAudioSource() step
 recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused
```

Comment: Good! Do you mind clicking the accept button next to this answer? That is the way we mark problems as resolved at stackoverflow.

Comment: I meant the `✔` check icon, it is at the top left of my answer. Check also the [stackoverflow tour here ;-)](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

You really need to provide the full error message and call stack if you want to get help for an exception.

Having said that, I can see a problem in your code (assuming you have provided all the relevant parts).

The 'recorder' member variable is never assigned a value, but is dereferenced in the try AND catch clauses of onCreate(). It is probably the dereference in the catch clause that is causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: @user3465656: I deleted the stack trace you added to my answer, as it belongs in your question, not in one of the proposed answers. Please also note that the reason you specify for making an edit to an answer is not displayed as a comment under that answer (for some reason).

Comment: i am new user so i facing problem this website how to use ,,,sorry for mistake

Comment: @user3465656: I understand :-). In addition, the stack trace you had inserted did not show a NullPointerException -- is that the entire stack trace, or have you changed your code? Please modify your question as appropriate.

Comment: now its working problem is in this line i am not add this line recorder.start();
  recorder.start();
  recorder.release();

Comment: If this question is answered, but you have a new follow-on question, please submit a new question for that. And please remember to include the relevant stack traces.